# std::map in C program

Tags: c++, c

I want to use `std::map` in my program, but I also have to use the libxml2 C library. Is there any option to use `map`? I know this is a structure of C++. I want to do simple mapping:

```cpp
std::map<string, string> name = {{ "name1", "name2" }, ... };
```

I don't usually use C, so I will be grateful for tips.

Comment: You can write an `extern C` wrapper for your C++, if you want.

Comment: So use C++? It's a lot easier to use a C library in a C++ program than the other way around.

Comment: @Shawn It's more "annoying" than "hard" since you have to go out of your way to write C wrappers versus just using it as-is.

Comment: Keep in mind if you're using `std::string` you'll need to convert those to `char*` for C as well. You can't expose anything C++-specific or C won't know how to deal.

Comment: *"but I also have to use libxml2 C"* - which you can do from a C++ program, so... sticking with C... *why* ?

Comment: Can someone find the right duplicate target?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `std::map` in a C program.  But you can use C libraries (like libxml2) in a C++ prgoram (in fact, I use libxml2 in my own C++ programs, it works just fine).